# Commerce Coupon "create coupon" link goes to empty white page

Tags: 7, commerce

So, I'm trying to add a simple percentage based coupon to a D7 site with the latest version of Commerce. I'm using the 7x-1.0beta7 version of Commerce Coupon and there seems to be a problem with UI. I have the module and all dependencies install, but when I try to navigate to the "Create Coupon" page from Admin =>Store => Coupon, get get taken to a white page with empty html at this URL `admin/commerce/coupons/add`. I can still add coupons through the "configure" button on the installed modules page, but this seems like a circuitous and round-about way of getting the necessary functionality. Any ideas on what's broken or how to fix it?

Comment: You should have a look at any watchdog entries relevant to (or created during) the loading of the coupons/add URL. If you see some error appearing there, please update your question. Cheers

Comment: Sounds like a module bug. Please scan through the module's issue queue on Drupal.org for this issue, or create a new one if it has not yet been reported.